# HTML - form field is not sent when containing special characters

Tags: php, html, http, forms

I have a `<form>` with several text inputs and a textarea. The documents Content-Type header is text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 and in the `<head>`-part I have a meta-tag with the same content-type: `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" />`. But when I type some special characters in one of the fields (like äüüß) the whole field is not sent, according to Firebug. What's the reason for that?

Comment: Did some of your formatting get eaten?  Did you mean to say "I have a &lt;form&gt; with several..." ?

Comment: yeah that's what i meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

was this included

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

EDIT: try using utf-8 in stead